# Is there an "IF NOT EXISTS" clause for adding columns in MySql?

Tags: mysql

I need to run this MySql code on some databases and I suspect that some of them to have already this column. Is there anything similar to `if not exists` for the below code?

```
ALTER TABLE 
    `comments` 
ADD COLUMN 
    `active` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' AFTER `sid`
```

I'm considering this to prevent getting the duplicated column error.

Comment: you have more than one table with the same table name (in a single DB) ?

Comment: no just i want to know if there is any option to exclude those sites that has an active column  actually to prevent getting duplicated column error !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not built-in, but it can be accomplished using the information_schema database:

http://www.cryer.co.uk/brian/mysql/howto_add_column_unless_exists.htm

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'tbl_name'
AND table_schema = 'db_name'
AND column_name = 'column_name'
```

should give you what you are looking for!!

Answer (score 1):

Or:
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE table_name = 'tbl_name'
    AND table_schema = 'db_name'
    AND column_name = 'column_name'

This gives you a 1 or 0 result based on existence or not.