# Alter ignore table add column if not exists using the SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1060

i want to add a new column to a mysql table, but i want to ignore the adding of column, if the column already exists

i am currently using

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `db`.`tablename` ADD COLUMN `column_name` text NULL;
```

but this is throwing an error saying : `"ERROR 1060 (42S21): Duplicate column name 'column_name'"`

even though i am using the IGNORE, this is not working

i want this to work using the normal SQL statement, instead of a stored procedure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html):

> IGNORE is a MySQL extension to standard SQL. It controls how ALTER
>   TABLE works if there are duplicates on unique keys in the new table or
>   if warnings occur when strict mode is enabled. If IGNORE is not
>   specified, the copy is aborted and rolled back if duplicate-key errors
>   occur. If IGNORE is specified, only one row is used of rows with
>   duplicates on a unique key. The other conflicting rows are deleted.
>   Incorrect values are truncated to the closest matching acceptable
>   value.

That is, it is used for a different purpose, not all errors.  What you want is something like `ALTER TABLE ADD IF NOT EXISTS`, and that syntax doesn't exist.

In a stored procedure, you can use an `if` statement to see if the column already exists (using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`).

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1e82f) is a SQL Fiddle that shows the same problem.